# Why would a button's value field by occasionally missing in an event callback

Tags: reactjs

Given an array of data, I use the first row to generate the headings, including a pair of buttons like this:

```
Object.keys(data[0]).map((key, i) => (
<Button size="sm" variant="link" 
  value={key} onClick={(event) => console.log(event.target.value)}>
    sort asc
</Button>
```

**The issue is that about a random half(ish) of clicks, event.target.value is undefined.**

There does not appear to be a pattern, but every 2nd, or 3rd click or so will find the value missing.

What am I missing?

This is react.

Comment: Probably `alert()` is confusing React rendering cycles since it synchronously blocks for long periods of time. Try using `console.log()` instead and checking the developer console with F12.

Comment: it isn't really calling alert - there is a function it calls. I changed it for the sake of a minimal example

Comment: is Button a component? does it have child nodes?

Comment: Is `onClick` an asynchronous function in your actual code? The event object is pooled so if you don't get `event.target.value` synchronously it might be unavailable by the time you're accessing it in the callback.

Comment: It's a bootstrap component. And the issue seems independent of what I name the value field.

Comment: Does the issue change based on *where* you click on the button? top edge, middle, left edge, right edge, etc

Comment: Haha Kevin figured it out my actual code has a FontAwesome icon, not text.
It fails if you click exactly on the icon.
Is there an easy fix? adding value to the icon does not do it

Comment: Yup, clicking a child node changes the event target

Comment: Can I force the event target to be the button itself?

Comment: Maybe because you haven't passed the `key` props? React should alert you in the console anyway

Comment: found currentTarget. Does exactly what I needed. Thanks all